# finding a harmonic sum using residues/complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, special-functions

Evaluate:

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2}$$

Using complex analysis.

I just needs **hints, I have no attempts,**

but I believe is has to do with residues.

Comment: Have you seen any similar problems done with residues?

Comment: I have but not with $H_n$

Comment: what is the meaning of $H_{n}$?

Comment: @Mark, probably $H_n=\sum_1^n(1/k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a lemma [you already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104141/residue-as-coefficient-of-laurent-series) to prove, if we take $f(z)=(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2$, the poles of $f(z)$ occur in $z=0,1,2,\ldots$ and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ we have:
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),z=n\right) = 2H_n,$$
so:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=-\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f(z)}{z^2},z=0\right)=-\operatorname{Res}\left(\left(\frac{\gamma+\psi(-z)}{z}\right)^2,z=0\right).\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, since in a punctured neighbourhood of $z=0$:
$$\gamma+\psi(-z) = \frac{1}{z}-\zeta(2) z-\zeta(3)z^2-\zeta(4)z^4+\ldots \tag{2}$$
it happens that:
$$\left(\frac{\gamma+\psi(-z)}{z}\right)^2=\frac{1}{z^4}-\frac{2\zeta(2)}{z^2}-\frac{2\zeta(3)}{z}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{2}+\ldots\tag{3}$$
so, by $(1)$,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\color{red}{2\,\zeta(3)}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Are you using the zeta definition of $\psi(-z) + \gamma$ in $(2)$ ?? Where can I see it?

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series

$$\psi(z+1) + \gamma = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \zeta(n+1)(-z)^n$$

$$\psi(-z) + \gamma = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \zeta(n+1)(z + 1)^n$$ this does give your series.

Comment: @Amad27, you are asking the same things over and over. The Laurent series in $(2)$ arises from considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function, or the integral representation of the $\psi$ function. Anyway, I remember you used relation $(2)$ somewhere, so you should be aware of its proof.

Comment: And remember that $\psi(z+1)=\frac{1}{z}+\psi(z)$.

Comment: Thank you Jack. So I believe you are using that Taylor series stated above. Very nice!

Comment: I think I see an issue here. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n/n^2 = \frac{\mathrm{Res}f(z)}{z^2}$$ It is not equal to: $$\mathrm{Res} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}$$

Comment: I cannot understand the meaning of what you wrote. You take the residue where? The key step here is that the sum of the residues of the function $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ is zero. The residues in $z=1,2,\ldots$ give the terms of the sum, hence the sum just depends on the residue in zero.

Comment: Here is the issue. We need $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2}$$ what I found was:

$$Res (\psi(-z) + \gamma)^2 = 2H_n \ne \frac{2H_n}{n^2}$$ So we will only have: 

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2H_n$$ which is not what we need.

Comment: I said: consider the residues of $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$, *not* the residues of $f(z)$.

Comment: Ok. So what is the residue of $$\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$$ at $z=n$? I am unable to find that.

Comment: Then you should stop asking these questions and study a bit more in depth the residue theory. The function $\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic in the punctured plane and has a double pole in zero. This is all you need to find the residues of $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ given the residues of $f(z)$.

Comment: I am trying to learn. Which is why I post at SE, because people help here (like your advice for example). So let me get this straight first. What is a **punctured plane** I searched it but got no hits? So you are also trying to find the residue of $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ at $z=n$ first right?  OR are you trying to find it at $0$?

Comment: Please help me! I can most likely understand it in some time! Dont give up please...

Comment: A punctured plane, Amad, is a plane with a point removed; in this case, the origin is the point that is removed. Do you not have a complex variables text where you can read about these things (instead of expecting Jack to be your private, free, tutor)? or maybe you have an instructor/lecturer/professor you can ask?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I am selfstudying this. I am not expecting any free-tutoring, I just thought maybe he could explain, I wasnt expecting anything which is why I asked. I have a book, but it doesnt explain this very well.